# Ping pong of a signal between 2 processes

Tags: bash, signals

I want to write 2 scripts that send a signal each other, like a ping-pong match, but with a signal, not a ball.

First script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=${PATH}:"/home/cosimo/Università/Sistemi Operativi/scripts"
exec player2pp.sh $$ &
trap "kill -SIGUSR1 $pidp2" SIGUSR1
sleep 2
```

Second script (player2pp.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "kill -SIGUSR1 $1" SIGUSR1
sleep 2
kill -SIGUSR1 $1
sleep 2
```

I got this error in `player2pp.sh`:

> kill: no corresponding process.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some problems:

1. you're launching the player2 script in the background, so you don't need `exec`
2. you don't store the PID of the player2 process anywhere
3. the first script launches player2, sleeps, then exits. You need to start some kind of infinite loop to avoid exiting.
4. if you kill the first script with Ctrl-C, the second script is left running in the background

Additionally, I would write a function for the trap so it's easier to do some logging:

player1pp.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/cosimo/Università/Sistemi Operativi/scripts"
./player2pp.sh $$ &
pidp2=$!
_ping() {
    echo "ping! killing $pidp2"
    kill -SIGUSR1 $pidp2
}
trap _ping SIGUSR1
trap "kill $pidp2" EXIT
while true; do sleep 2; done
```

player2pp.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
pidp1=$1
_pong() {
    echo "pong! killing $pidp1"
    kill -SIGUSR1 $pidp1
}
trap _pong SIGUSR1
_pong   # start the game
while true; do sleep 2; done
```

---

For fun, add some randomness:

Player 1

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/cosimo/Università/Sistemi Operativi/scripts"
./player2pp.sh $$ &
opponent=$!

ping() {
    sleep=$((RANDOM % 5))
    echo "ping! killing $opponent in $sleep"
    sleep $sleep
    kill -USR1 $opponent
}
trap ping USR2

cleanup () {
    kill -0 $opponent && kill $opponent
}
trap cleanup EXIT

ping
while :; do :; done
```

Player 2

```
#!/bin/bash
opponent=$1

pong() {
    sleep=$((RANDOM % 5))
    echo "pong! killing $opponent in $sleep"
    sleep $sleep
    kill -USR2 $opponent
}
trap pong USR1

cleanup () {
    kill -0 $opponent && kill $opponent
}
trap cleanup EXIT

while :; do :; done
```